# MySql Неоднозначное поведение NULL в IN условии

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Почему этот запрос выводит пользователей:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE NOT 23 IN (1, 2, 4, 43);
```

А этот нет:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE NOT 23 IN (1, 2, 4, 43, NULL);
```

И как сделать чтобы выводил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таково требование стандарта SQL. Не смогу привести однозначную краткую цитату, но стандарт относит `IN` к `equality operations`, аналогично прочим операторам сравнения, а потому к `IN` так же применяется общая троичная логика. Выражение

```
foo in (1,2,NULL)
```

эквивалентно

```
foo = 1 OR foo = 2 OR foo = NULL
```

которое для любого `foo` будет `NULL`. А, в свою очередь, `NULL` в выражении `where` означает "нет совпадения"

Сделать с этим можно что-то разумное только одно - проверяйте подставляемые в условия данные на стороне приложения и не подставляйте `NULL`.